# Stax parser ignore encoding

Tags: stax

I am parsing a XML file with Stax parser which has encoding mentioned as encoding="UTF-16", 
But the actual content of this XML file is not UTF-16. How can i tell the Stax parser to ignore the encoding mentioned in the file and do auto detect based on the content

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what method of StAX-Parsing you use (`XMLStreamReader` vs. `XMLEventReader`), you can pass the encoding to the create-Method of the `XMLInputFactory`.

- createXMLStreamReader(InputStream stream, String encoding)
- createXMLEventReader(InputStream stream, String encoding)

If none specified, some StAX implementations try to "guess" the actual encoding (Weblogic's StAX-Implementation, for instance, tries to do that), whereas others would use the JVM's Default-Encoding (System-Property `file.encoding`; careful: has to be set at startup already, no change at runtime).

If you want/have to figure out the encoding on your own, you would have to implement this on your own. I had to do this once and - based on the requirements, specifications and environment I had back then - ended up with a little and not really very nice trial-and-error approach where I had to try all the encodings I supported in my system. One after the other until I had a "good enough match". I also had to be very careful about [BOMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (Byte Order Marks).

In general I believe that the XML-Prologue should hold the correct encoding, because whatever's done in the code can only be a best-guess (however, this guess can also be right).

And as a personal note, that might be terribly wrong but works well for me: Since XML mainly is Input Data, I strongly believe in [GIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
byte[] byteArray = null;
        try {
            if (something)) {
                byteArray = sourceXMLString.getBytes(Constants.ENCODING_UTF_16);
            } else {
                byteArray = sourceXMLString.getBytes(Constants.ENCODING_ISO_8859_1);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

        try {
            xmlEventReaderSource = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(inputStream);

        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            logger.error("ERROR is StAX reader initialization" + e.getLocalizedMessage());

        }
```

Comment: please add the least bit details about your code, not just a code.